# CSS Footer background no full on iPad browser

Tags: css, ipad, magento, footer

I have add a footer background image.It's look perfect on my PC. But it show up not correct on iPad browser. I'm try to upload image to show you guy but i'm very new on stackoverflow so i can't upload.If anyone know how to show you guy an image. Please let me know i will upload it. Please have a look at the Black part bottom right. Anyone please help me to fix this problem

Thank you

I add this line to my css.

```
.footer{ border-top: 4px solid #00b0bd; }
.footer a{ color: #000000;}
.footer-container { width:100%; text-align: left; background: url("../images/footer/footer_damask.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;}
.footer { margin: 0 auto 15px; width: 960px; }
.aditional-footer { margin:0 auto 0; padding: 30px 0 30px; width: 960px; background-image:none !important;}
.footer .links li { text-transform: none; }
.footer-container a { color:#666669; font-size: 11px; width: 960px; }
.footer-container .footer-right { width: 250px; }
.footer .f-right { width:429px; text-align: right; padding-right:20px; }
```

this is my full CSS.

```
/* Footer ================================================================================ */
.footer-social-container { width:100%; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #404040; border-top: 0 solid #00aebb;}
.footer-social { width:960px; padding: 5px 0; margin:0 auto; }
.footer-social .phone { color:#111; float:right; font-size:16px; }
.footer-social .follow_us { display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; margin: 0; float: left; color:#ffffff; }
.footer-social .twitter,
.footer-social .rss,
.footer-social .facebook { margin-left: 5px; text-indent: -9999px; display: inline-block; float: left; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center; height:24px; width:30px; }
.footer-social .twitter:hover,
.footer-social .rss:hover,
.footer-social .facebook:hover { background-position: bottom center; }
.footer-social .twitter { background-image: url(../images/twitter.png); }
.footer-social .rss { background-image: url(../images/rss.png); }
.footer-social .facebook { background-image: url(../images/facebook.png); }
.footer-social  .gift_img { float: left; border-left: 1px solid #00afbc; border-right: 1px solid #00afbc; padding: 0 50px; margin: 0 0 0 100px; } 

.footer{ border-top: 4px solid #00b0bd; }
.footer a{ color: #000000;}

.footer-container { width:100%; text-align: left; background: url("../images/footer/footer_damask.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;}

.footer { margin: 0 auto 15px; width: 960px; }
.aditional-footer { margin:0 auto 0; padding: 30px 0 30px; width: 960px; background-image:none !important;}
.footer .links li { text-transform: none; }
.footer-container a { color:#666669; font-size: 11px; width: 960px; }
.footer-container .footer-right { width: 250px; }

.footer .f-right { width:429px; text-align: right; padding-right:20px; }

.footer ul { display:inline; }
.footer li { display:inline; background:url(../images/bkg_pipe1.gif) 100% 50% no-repeat; padding:0 5px 0 0; margin:0 3px 0 0; }
.footer .links li.last { background:none !important; padding-right:0 !important; }
.footer .bugs { margin:0; color:#666; }
.footer .bugs a { font-weight:bold; color:#353535; }
.footer address { color:#666; }
.footer address a { color:#353535; }

.policy li { margin-left:2px; padding-left:10px ; line-height: 1.5; background: url(../images/footer_li.png) no-repeat left top;}
.policy li:hover { background: url(../images/footer_li.png) no-repeat left bottom;}

.footer-container .form-subscribe { }
.footer-container .form-subscribe label { padding-top:2px; font-weight:bold; color:#555; }
.footer-container .form-subscribe .input-box { border: 1px solid #EFEFEF; width: auto; float: left; height: 27px;}
.footer-container .form-subscribe button.button { float:left; width: 58px;}
.footer-container .form-subscribe button.button span { height: 22px; font: normal 11px/22px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
.footer-container .form-subscribe input.input-text { width: 180px; border: 0px solid #d6d4d4; border-right:0; padding: 0; padding-left: 8px; float:left; height: 27px; line-height: 27px; }
.footer-container .form-subscribe input.input-text:focus { border: 1px solid #FF292C; border-right: 0; height: 25px; line-height: 15px }
.footer-container .form-subscribe input.input-text.validation-failed { background: none!important; border-right:0!important; }
.footer-container .form-subscribe .validation-advice { position: absolute; width: 171px; margin-top: 31px; background: white; padding:5px; }

.footer-container .footer-callout { display:block; margin:-10px 0 10px; position:relative; }
.footer-container .store-switcher { color:#555; text-align:right; }
.footer-container .store-switcher label { font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle; }
.footer-container .store-switcher select { padding:0; vertical-align:middle; }

.footer-container .bottom-container { margin:0 0 8px; text-align:right; }
/* ======================================================================================= */
```

Comment: Could you provide a working exemple, a link to your site or a screencap of your problem ?

Comment: Hi, I have screencap of my problem. http://emocase.com/show/photo111.PNG Please have a look on bottom right of the page. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not an iPad specific problem, rather a low horizontal resolution one. I've the same bug in Chrome when my window is narrow.

Why ?

Your `.page` is `960px` wide, overflowing your `body` which is `100%` (768px on iPad)

Your footer is 100% width, so the same width than your `body`, 768px.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Anyway to fix this problem.Thank you